# Is this a true implementation of XOR in python?

Tags: python, encryption

I have implemented a simple XOR encryption in Python. However I am not sure this is the right implementation or it can be further improved ?

```
from math import ceil
from random import uniform

from numpy import array, repeat, vectorize


#---------- HELPER FUNCTIONS ----------#


def addtrailingzero(byte):
    """
    Adding trailing zero's if the length of the byte is less then 0.
    
    Example:
    addtrailingzero('110110')
    >>>00110110
    """
    while len(byte) != 8:
        byte = '0' + byte
    return byte


def byteArray(text):
    """
    Turning the given text into an array, where each element contains the binary representation
    of each text element.

    Args:
        text [str]: It can be either a message or a key

    Returns:
        [array]: an array that contains the byte information of each string element

    Example:
    byteArray('12')
    >>>['00110001' '00110010']
    byteArray('hey')
    >>>['01101000' '01100101' '01111001']
    """
    binary_text = array([bin(ord(char))[2:] for char in text])
    vectorizeF = vectorize(addtrailingzero)
    byteArray_text = vectorizeF(binary_text)
    return byteArray_text


def resizeKey(message, key):
    """
    Resizing the length of the key, in order to perform XOR operations easily.

    Args:
        message [str]: The input message that is going to be encrypted
        key [str]: The key that generated randomly, or entered by the user
    """
    byteArray_key = byteArray(key)
    messageLength = len(message)
    keyLength = len(key)
    r = ceil(messageLength/keyLength)
    resize_byteArray_key = repeat(byteArray_key, r)
    resize_byteArray_key = resize_byteArray_key[:messageLength]
    return resize_byteArray_key


def binaryArraytoString(binary_array):
    """
    Turning any binary array into a string

    Args:
        binary_array [list]: An array consists of series of bits
    
    Example:
    binaryArraytoString('011001100110111101101111')
    >>> 'foo'
    """
    lenBinArray = len(binary_array)
    return ''.join([chr(int(binary_array[i:i+8], 2)) for i in range(0, lenBinArray, 8)])


#----------------------------#


def encryptXOR(message, key):
    """
    Encrypting the message for a given key

    Args:
        message [str]: The input message that is going to be encrypted
        key [str]: The key that generated randomly, or entered by the user

    Returns:
        Encrypted message
    """
    byteArray_message = byteArray(message)
    byteArray_key = resizeKey(message, key)

    binaryArray_message = ''.join(byteArray_message)
    binaryArray_key = ''.join(byteArray_key)

    encryptedBinary_message = ''
    for (i, j) in list(zip(binaryArray_message, binaryArray_key)):
        # performing the XOR operation
        encryptedBinary_message += str(int(i) ^ int(j))
    encrypted_message = binaryArraytoString(encryptedBinary_message) # recovering the encrypted message from the binary array
    return encrypted_message


def generateKey(key_length):
    """
    Generating random keys for a given length
    """
    binary_key = ''
    for i in range(key_length * 8):
        if uniform(0, 1) < 0.5:
            binary_key += '1'
        else:
            binary_key += '0'
    randomKey = binaryArraytoString(binary_key)
    return randomKey


def decryptXOR(encrypted_message, key):
    """
    Encrypting the message for a given key

    Args:
        encrypted_message [str]: The encrypted message
        key [str]: The key that generated randomly, or entered by the user

    Returns:
        Encrypted message
    """
    byteArray_message = byteArray(encrypted_message)
    byteArray_key = resizeKey(encrypted_message, key)

    binaryArray_message = ''.join(byteArray_message)
    binaryArray_key = ''.join(byteArray_key)

    decryptedBinary_message = ''
    for (i, j) in list(zip(binaryArray_message, binaryArray_key)):
        # performing the XOR operation
        decryptedBinary_message += str(int(i) ^ int(j))
    decrypted_message = binaryArraytoString(decryptedBinary_message) # recovering the encrypted message from the binary array
    return decrypted_message

encrypted_text = encryptXOR('I have a dream', '12p')
decrypted_text = decryptXOR(encrypted_text, '12p')

print(encrypted_text)
print(decrypted_text)
```

Answer (score 7):

You're converting your text to ASCII ordinals (good-ish) but then converting those ordinals to binary-formatted strings (deeply ungood). A change of thinking is needed: rather than managing a string where every single character is either an ASCII "1" or an ASCII "0", you need to understand that byte arrays such as

```
b'I have a dream'
```

equivalent to the output of

```
'I have a dream'.encode()
```

*are already binary* in memory. Each character here maps to one byte, which takes up eight bits in memory. Exclusive-or bitwise operations can and should operate on these bytes directly. It's doubtful that Numpy will be of any benefit here.

Answer (score 5):

### Code review

```
def addtrailingzero(byte):
```

Trailing zero's are generally thought of as being at the right hand side; English is read from left to right. You are left-padding the bits with zeros; the name should reflect that.

---

```
binary_text = array([bin(ord(char))[2:] for char in text])
vectorizeF = vectorize(addtrailingzero)
byteArray_text = vectorizeF(binary_text)
```

This is hugely inefficient: first creating an array of a dynamic size, then adding each byte value and then reiterating over it. Instead, you should perform the operation on each byte before adding it to the array. In this case you should however simply use `format(ord('M'), "0>8b")`, which uses formatting with `0` as padding character, right aligning `>` the binary encoding `b` of the given integer returned by `ord`.

---

```
 def resizeKey(message, key):
```

Please note that repeating key values is completely insecure; it is called a "many-time pad" (as compared to the secure one-time pad) and can be broken almost instantly. And you don't have to resize the key at all; you can just using modular indexing (`key_index = index % key_size`) on the key length.

---

```
resize_byteArray_key = repeat(byteArray_key, r)
resize_byteArray_key = resize_byteArray_key[:messageLength]
```

I know that Python is a higher level language; but please note that creating an array of the right size and then filling the array is much more performant. As it is, you would be winding up rewriting the application if you need it to perform well. If you use your constructs right then Python can be *concise and performant*.

---

```
if uniform(0, 1) < 0.5:
```

There is one thing that cryptographers don't like in their code: floating point. The reason for this is that floating point usually introduces rounding errors. Rounding errors may create bias, and bias in XOR means that the ciphertext may be biased as well. Biased output is [can be distinguished from random](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability).

`uniform` also isn't cryptographically secure. Using a non-secure random number generator is a complete no-go in cryptography. Instead you should be using `random.SystemRandom().randrange(2)` from the build in `random` module. If you look into that module you will also find methods for generating random bits and even bytes. However, while we are at it, you could just use [secrets.token_bytes()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#secrets.token_bytes).

Always beware of using deprecated methods. From the Numpy API documentation:

> New code should use the uniform method of a default_rng() instance instead; please see the Quick Start.

---

```
def decryptXOR(encrypted_message, key):
```

One of the nice things of the XOR cipher is that encryption is identical to decryption. When implemented correctly, you should be able to use only one place where you do the XOR. If you still want an `encrypt` and `decrypt` function then that's fine: just call a `crypt` function from both of them.

### Shorter and better (spoiler alert!)

Here is code that:

- creates an actual, cryptographically secure key
- uses Pythoneske method names
- uses a generator to cycle over the characters of the key
- performs explicit ASCII encoding to go from text to binary
- but otherwise generates as few strings / byte arrays as possible

**Python 3 version**

```
from secrets import token_bytes

def crypt_xor(message, key):
    result = bytearray(message)
    for i, k in enumerate(cycle(key, len(message))):
        result[i] ^= k
    return result

def cycle(s, max):
    n = len(s)
    return (s[i % n] for i in range(max))

key = bytes(token_bytes(3))
encrypted_text = crypt_xor('I have a dream'.encode('ascii'), key)
decrypted_text = crypt_xor(encrypted_text, key)
print(decrypted_text.decode('ascii'))
```

Note that that the module `itertools` also contains a `cycle` method, but it caches the whole string, because it doesn't know that the iterable that it takes as input can be reset to the start again.

**One liner in Python 3**

OK, put it in a function, let's not overdo it.

```
def crypt_xor(message, key):
    return bytes(m ^ key[i % len(key)] for i, m in enumerate(message))
```

**Python 2 version**

```
from os import urandom

def crypt_xor(message, key):
    result = ''
    for (m, k) in zip(message, cycle(key, len(message))):
        result += chr(ord(m) ^ ord(k))
    return result

def cycle(s, max):
    n = len(s)
    return (s[i % n] for i in range(max))

key = urandom(3)
encrypted_text = crypt_xor(b'I have a dream', key)
decrypted_text = crypt_xor(encrypted_text, key)
print(decrypted_text)
```

Comment: This is more like a code review, but please note that I wholeheartely agree with [this answer about using actual bits instead of the characters `'0'` and `'1'`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/264399/9555).